# PHP controlling small database - add and edit (query)

Tags: php, sql, post, mysqli, radio-button

New to PHP and SQL so I have created a small databas for movies and I am having some problems which I have not been able to solve yet.

1. How to create a working edit function? In order to be able to edit
   the movies that are in the databas.
2. How to get the value from the radio buttons into SQL value for    categories?

Hopefully this is not too much code.

```
<?php
  require_once 'login.php';
  // Connection to databas
  $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
  {   
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_error . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
  }
  // Delete movie from databas
  if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id']))
  {
    $id = get_post($conn, 'id');
    $query = "DELETE FROM Movies WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "Delete failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }
    // Edit movie


  $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "title", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $director = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "director", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $year = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "year", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $category = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "category", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

  if (isset($_POST['title']) &&
      isset($_POST['director']) &&
      isset($_POST['year']) &&
      isset($_POST['radio']) &&
      isset($_POST['id']))
  {
    $title = get_post($conn, 'title');
    $director = get_post($conn, 'director');
    $year = get_post($conn, 'year');
    $category = get_post($conn, 'category');
    $id = get_post($conn, 'id');
    $query = "INSERT INTO Movies VALUES" .
  "('$title', '$director', '$year', '$category', '$id')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }
  // Form for adding movies and radiobuttons for categories
  echo <<<_END
  <form action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
     Title: <input type="text" name="title">
     Director: <input type="text" name="director">
     Year: <input type="text" name="year">
     Category: 
     <input type="radio" name="query" value="1"> Action
     <input type="radio" name="query" value="2"> Animated
     <input type="radio" name="query" value="3"> Drama
     <input type="radio" name="query" value="4"> Fantasy
     <input type="radio" name="query" value="5"> Sci-Fi
     <input type="radio" name="query" value="6"> Thriller
     <input type="submit" value="Add Movie">
  </pre></form>
_END;

  // List all movies from databas
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM movies";

  $result = $conn->query($query);
   if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);
  $rows = $result->num_rows;

  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
  {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo <<<_END
  <pre>
     Title $row[0]
     Director $row[1]
     Year $row[2]
     Category $row[3]
  </pre>
  <form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[4]">
  <input type="submit" value="Edit movie"></form>
  <form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[4]">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete movie"></form>
_END;
  }

  $result->close();
  $conn->close();

  function get_post($conn, $var)
  {
    return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what exactly is your problem? I can see you have the edit functionality but the mistake you have is that you're trying to insert but you have to call update since the data is already in the database. And for your second question it's also just a number what do you mean by converting it to sql value?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your script (not using all table information). But you'll see, that it is much easy. But, please use PDO instead of mysql or mysqli extension of PHP. In future these extensions will be removed from PHP. PDO is a great way to handle db transactions.

My script is working for insert, edit and remove records, but it should only represent how it worked in general.

please replace database credentials for the mysql connection (localhost,testdb, root,password)

```
<?php

$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=testdb', 'root', 'password', [
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
]);

$categories = [
    'None',
    'Action',
    'Animated',
    'Drama'
];

if (array_key_exists('action', $_GET)) {
    switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'add':
            $query = 'INSERT INTO Movies SET title = :title, category = :category';
            $handle = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $handle->bindValue(':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $handle->bindValue(':category', $_POST['category'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $handle->execute();
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            die;
        case 'edit':
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE id = :id';
            $handle = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $handle->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $handle->execute();
            $record = $handle->fetch();

            $categoriesHtml = '';
            foreach ($categories as $catid => $cat) {
                $selected = $catid == $record['category'] ? 'checked' : '';
                $categoriesHtml .= '<input type="radio" name="category" value="' . $catid . '" ' . $selected . ' /> ' . $cat . '<br>';
            }

            echo <<<HTML
<form method="post" action="?action=save">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$_GET['id']}" />
    <input name="title" value="{$record['title']}" /><br/>
    {$categoriesHtml}
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
HTML;
            break;
        case 'save':
            $query = 'UPDATE Movies SET title = :title, category = :category WHERE id = :id';
            $handle = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $handle->bindValue(':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $handle->bindValue(':category', $_POST['category'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $handle->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $handle->execute();
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            die;
        case 'delete':
            $query = 'DELETE FROM Movies WHERE id = :id';
            $handle = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $handle->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $handle->execute();
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            die;
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    die;
}
echo '<ul>';
// List
$handle = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM Movies');
foreach ($handle->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo <<<HTML
<li>
    {$row['title']} - <a href="?action=edit&id={$row['id']}">edit</a> <a href="?action=delete&id={$row['id']}">delete</a>
</li>
HTML;
}
echo '</ul>';

$categoriesHtml = '';
foreach ($categories as $catid => $cat) {
    $categoriesHtml .= '<input type="radio" name="category" value="' . $catid . '" /> ' . $cat . '<br>';
}

echo <<<HTML
<form method="post" action="?action=add">
    <input name="title" value="" />
    <br/>
    {$categoriesHtml}
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
HTML;
```